# (Really simple question) Having multiple values for a variable in an if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm a python newbie and I know this is super simple by I can't find the proper answer. I wrote some code to annoy my friend George that's designed to say 'this person is cool' for any answer you input except 'George'

```
uncool = "George"
if input("Who do you think is cool?\n") == uncool:
    print("this person is not cool")
else:
    print("This person is cool")
```

I know this is simple: I want to make it so that both "George" and "george" are values for the 'uncool' variable. I've tried putting them both in a list, but that meant that typing just 'George' or 'george' on its own didn't work anymore. How do i edit this code so the if statement is triggered by multiple different values?

Comment: Use uncool.lower() in the statement

Comment: @nithin11: Though that (assuming both values are converted to matching case) also allows `"gEorGe"` and the like to count as "uncool". If it's just two things to match, you'd go with `if input("Who do you think is cool?\n") in ("George", "george"):` or the like.

Comment: @nithin11 AND use .lower() on the input value as well.

Comment: Yes @RufusVS Thats correct

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use `lower()` function in your code:

```
uncool = "George".lower()
if input("Who do you think is cool?\n").lower() == uncool:
    print("this person is not cool")
else:
    print("This person is cool")
```

Result:

```
Who do you think is cool?
george
this person is not cool
```

Another result:

```
Who do you think is cool?
gEorge
this person is not cool
```

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section *Answer Well-Asked Questions*, and therein the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: Fix your answer.  Your Result section is not the result.   Besides, you should use lower() on the input value as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
userinput = input("Who do you think is cool?\n")
if userinput  == "George" or userinput == "george":
    print("this person is not cool")
else:
    print("This person is cool")
```

Comment: What about `"gEorge"`?

Comment: I accept using `lower()` function would do better but he only asked for `George`  and `george`. So, I provided a different and simpler approach.